# How to use async/await for not-async io-operation? such as get/put in leveldb

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, leveldb

I want to use async/await for database, but I don't know how to do it.

And I found that [mongodb](https://crates.io/crates/mongodb) has a async/await driver based on async conections.

But [levelDB](https://crates.io/crates/leveldb) is not async.

What should I do?

I read the [tokio](https://tokio.rs/) document, may be I can use [spawn_blocking](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.21.0/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) to run a async io-task.

Is it right? If I frequently use `spawn_blocking`, will it affect the performance?

Comment: Yep `spawn_blocking` is what you want.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the DB async (don't; `spawn_blocking()` will be less performant than threads, perhaps use a thread pool), or "what to do if I have already async code and I want to integrate the DB into it?" (in this case `spawn_blocking()` is great)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The problem I'm having should be the latter one you describe. Based on @corinjg 's answer, I'm trying to wrap the operation with `spawn_blocking()` and then use `channel` communication with the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spawn_blocking](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.21.0/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) part of the Tokio API uses a separate thread pool (to the core threads used for async tasks) with a configurable keep-alive time if threads are unused. So you may incur the overhead of spawning a new system thread. If you're always performing the same blocking tasks, a possible optimization could be to use a [channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html#communicating-between-sync-and-async-code) to communicate between async tasks and a single long running sync task which retrieves messages containing the parameters from the channel.

Comment: Wow, using a channel is a great idea. Thank you very much